Arduino Mega 2560 Oscilloscope
I'm trying to make a little oscilloscope with arduino mega 2560 board. In the following snippet there's the function in pc client code that handles received bytes of data from board samples. When dysplayed they are correct but are not correctly written on a text file. Instead on the text file there are incremental numbers from 1 to an enormous value. Where is the problem in the fprintf?
void receive_data(int fd, const char *filename, int num_channels, int mode) {
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "w");
    if (!file) {
        perror("Errore nell'apertura del file");
        return;
    }
    uint8_t buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
    int bytes_per_sample = num_channels * 3; // 1 byte di sincronizzazione + 2 bytes per canale
    int buffer_offset = 0;
    time_t start_time = time(NULL);
    //unsigned int sample_count = 0; // Contatore dei campioni

    printf("Campionamento in corso per 10 secondi...\n");

    while (time(NULL) - start_time < 10) {
        int bytes_read = read(fd, buffer + buffer_offset, sizeof(buffer) - buffer_offset);
        if (bytes_read > 0) {
            bytes_read += buffer_offset;
            int i = 0;
         while (i <= bytes_read - bytes_per_sample) {
            // For each channel, look for a sync byte
            int sync_found = 1;
            for (int ch = 0; ch < num_channels; ch++) {
                if (buffer[i++] != 0xAA) {
                    sync_found = 0;
                    break;
                }
                // Read high and low bytes for the channel
                if (bytes_read - i < 2) {
                    // Not enough data, handle buffer offset
                    break;
                }
                uint8_t high_byte = buffer[i++];
                uint8_t low_byte = buffer[i++];
                uint16_t value = ((uint16_t)high_byte << 8) | low_byte;
                printf("%u ", value);
                fprintf(file, "%u", value);
                if (ch < num_channels - 1) {
                    fprintf(file, " ");
                }
            }
            if (!sync_found) {
                // Realign buffer if sync byte not found
                while (i < bytes_read && buffer[i] != 0xAA) {
                    i++;
                }
                buffer_offset = bytes_read - i;
                memmove(buffer, &buffer[i], buffer_offset);
                break;
            }
            printf("\n");
            fprintf(file, "\n");
            fflush(file);
         }
            // Gestisci eventuali bytes rimasti nel buffer
            if (i < bytes_read) {
                buffer_offset = bytes_read - i;
                memmove(buffer, &buffer[i], buffer_offset);
            } else {
                buffer_offset = 0;
            }
        } else if (bytes_read == 0) {
            usleep(1000); // Attendi 1ms
        } else {
            perror("Errore nella lettura dalla porta seriale");
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
}


If necessary i can show other parts of code

What is MAX_BUFFER_SIZE? You allocate an array of this size on the stack, which may be unwise if the value is large. Many systems only support fairly small stack sizes. Consider allocating with malloc() or similar, or move it out to file scope.

It's hard to see why printf("%u ", value); fprintf(file, "%u", value); (with following space) will generate different outputs. Is the file you are looking at created with the right date and time?


I would recommend to change fprintf(file, "%u", value); to fprintf(file, " %04X", value); to investigate this problem. 2) Are you certain buffer[] data is in big endian order and that it is phase?


Can you show an example of output to stdout and incorrect file content for the same data?

After a 0xAA sync byte, can either of the per-channel data bytes have a 0xAA value? BTW, to simplify, replace the fprintf statements with fprintf(" %u",value);

Your recovery from a missing sync byte seems problematic. If you're in the for (ch = 0; ...) loop, if the first byte isn't sync, you rescan for it, but you start again at channel 0. What if channel 1 had the missing sync byte? How should you recover?

Also, if the read returns a partial non-zero length, your code may get confused. That is (e.g.) with 3 channels, if the return value is 5, and eventually you will get a valid buffer with AA,c0[0],c0[1],AA,c1[0],c1[1],AA,c2[0],c2[1] for total length of 9 (e.g. next read returns 4), you should wait before trying to process the buffer. As is, you don't handle this correctly. Again, this is because you always start the loop with ch = 0;
